# How does this function returning a function work?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what is happening in the code here and how this script is changing other functions.

This is taken from eloquentjavascript.net chapter 5 on higher order functions.

```
function noisy(f) {
  return function(arg) {
    console.log("calling with", arg);
    var val = f(arg);
    console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
    return val;
  };
}
noisy(Boolean)(0);

// → calling with 0
// → called with 0 - got false
```

Comment: The [code edit](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/308692/revisions) was Eric. I was more concerned about the "Can you explain higher order functions to me" being something that people might answer without trying to answer the bit about *this* code... and that question is a bit on the broad side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it's not clear what part of this is confusing you, let's take this step by step.

1) `Boolean` is a function. In this case, it takes one argument, and returns either true or false depending on whether the argument was truthy or falsy. So if it helps, you could replace `Boolean` with `function(x) { return !!x; }` and get roughly the same behavior.

2) This line:

```
noisy(Boolean)(0);
```

is interchangeable with:

```
var func = noisy(Boolean);
func(0);
```

Assuming the identifier `func` is not used anywhere else in your code.

3) `noisy(Boolean)` obviously calls the `noisy` function, with `f` set to the function `Boolean`. The call to `noisy` then returns a function like this:

```
function(arg) {
    console.log("calling with", arg);
    var val = Boolean(arg);
    console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
    return val;
}
```

4) The function returned by `noisy` is then called with `0` as the value of `arg`. That effectively does the following:

```
console.log("calling with", 0);
var val = Boolean(0);
console.log("called with", 0, "- got", val);
return val;
```

5) If #1 made sense, then it shouldn't be surprising that `Boolean(0)` evaluates to `false`. From there it should be obvious why the output is what it is.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the line `noisy(Boolean)(0);`

`Boolean` [is a javascript function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) that takes an optional parameter.

The first part of the line in question, **noisy(Boolean)**(0); , takes the Boolean function, and passes it into the `noisy` function as a parameter.

The `noisy` function returns a (new) function that takes a parameter (`return function(arg)`).

The second half of the line in question, noisy(Boolean)**(0)**; , takes the return value of noisy (a function that takes a parameter) and invokes it with the parameter `0`;

The function that `noisy` returns will do a couple of console writes, but in between will invoke the function that was originally sent into `noisy` (the `Boolean` function, called `f`) with the parameter (`0`, called `arg`), and then capture and pass on Boolean's return value through the variable `val`.

---

I think that it is misleading to say that this is changing any function. This code is creating a new function that wraps an existing function with extra functionality.

In this case, this code simply wraps the `Boolean` function with a couple of console.log calls, but the `Boolean` function remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

First keep in mind that this code is not changing/mutating the passed in function.  Passing in the Boolean constructor is a bit odd and may lead to some confusion so lets remove it and break it down more for clarity.

```
var noisyIsArray = noisy(Array.isArray);

noisyIsArray([]);
> calling with []
> called with [] - got true
true

noisyIsArray(2);
> calling with 2
> called with 2 - got false
false
```

In its simplest form noisy can take any function and return a function.  Inside of the function that it returns it calls the function that it takes in.  Before calling it, it just logs the arguments and returns value.

In the above case `Array.isArray` is the function that we are passing into `noisy` and `var noisyIsArray` is a function as well (the function returned by noisy).

Here is a very simple (and not robust) higher order function :

```
function logSomething() {
    console.log('something');
}

function invoke(fn) {
    return function() {
        fn();
    }
}

var invokeLogSomething = invoke(logSomething);

invokeLogSomething();
>something
```

All `invoke` does is take a function and return a function that calls the passed in function.  There is nothing special about the `fn` function call is just like any other one.

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript snipped implements and show two particular points :

- a *Closure*: that is a special habitability of some languages to capture a variable into another context.
- the fact that in Javascript any variable is an object (a string, an integer, a function, a class, ...)

This snipped finally provide a function *noisy()* that can run another function with extra debug information.

Let's see step by step :

```
function noisy(f)
```

This function takes a function as argument. No problem: with JS a function is also an object.

```
return function(arg) {
```

The *noisy()* function returns another function without a name (an *anonymous* function). Still no problem: with JS a function is also an object.

You can notice that the argument `f` is not use anywhere in function *noisy()*. It is used only in the anonymous function. If you don't know about *Closure* you should think that argument `f` is superfluous in *noisy()*, and that it should raise an error in the anonymous function since it is not declared a local nor global. In fact, because of the Closure feature, argument `f` is actually passed to the anonymous function as a variable, and this variable is closed in the context of the function. That is the variable `f` is no more linked to argument `f` after the anonymous function is actually created.

The other part of the functions is quite simple : the anonymous function run the function `f` and log some debug info in the console, before and after.

The last part of the snipped is a test of the function.

```
noisy(Boolean)(0);
```

It is tested with the class *Boolean*. This is a strange choice for a test, but is works because in JS a class is an object. Calling a class as a function simply creates a new object of that type. Another well know example is `Date('2016-01-01')`.

Comment: In Javascript, almost everything is a function, not an object.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman  A function is always an object (it has methods `call()` and `apply()`). While a string is not, an integer is not, .... try `("hello")()` and you will have an error `TypeError: "hello" is not a function`.

Comment: In javascript, Boolean is an _object_ of type 'function', but it's not a _class_.